# Line bundle on the Jacobian of a curve which restricts to the canonical bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $J$, the Jacobian of a smooth projective genus two curve  $C$over complex numbers. Let $L$ be a line bundle such that $L|_C$ is $K_C$, the canonical bundle of $C$. Can we say that $L\simeq O_J(C)$. If not, is there some relation between these two line bundles. Do we know that $L$ has a section?

Comment: The right side of your isomorphism has no sense as a line bundle, unless $g = 2$, since $C \subset J$ is not a divisor.

Comment: @Sasha, I have mentioned in the question that the genus is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(C) = 2$ so that $C \subset J$ is a divisor, then by adjunction
$$
K_C = (K_J + C)\vert_C = C\vert_C
$$
since $K_J = 0$. So, indeed, $L = O_J(C)$ works.

Since the restriction map $Pic^0(J) \to Pic^0(C)$ is an isomorphism, this is the only line bundle with this property.

Comment: that is right. But my question is can we have a line bundle $L\neq O_J(C)$ such that $L|_C$ is $K_C$.

Comment: @user349424: No, we can't, see my edit.